# MYSQL Collations [utf8_general_ci] and [utf8_unicode_ci]. What's the difference?

Tags: mysql, encoding, charset

I'm wondering if there any different between these tow Collations in mysql encoding charset UTF8:
**`utf8_general_ci`** and **`utf8_unicode_ci`**
They both looks the same!
note: For now I'm writing in them in English only, But I'm afraid if it has a side-effect if I inserted in another language like Arabic.

Comment: My current conclusion is: using utf8_unicode_ci to ensure wider/better character support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search on google and I found [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,187048); there is a good explanation.